# Redis restarts with protected mode by default - how to change this

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I've been having a problem with a site for quite some time. I'm not the original developer and Redis is not a strong point of mine at all - to the point where I have **no** experience with it at all.

Occasionally, our Redis server just crashes and causes our main site to break. It then restarts in protected mode. This has a simple fix - just restart the redis-server application with protected mode off.

However, I'd like it to restart itself on a crash with protected mode turned off. I'd also like to look deeper into why this is happening but the log files have been of no use at all.

The `/etc/redis/redis.conf` file contains `protected-mode no` but this seems to have no effect.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your redis-server isn't started with that config file. Protected mode is on by default, which is what you're describing. You should look into what's actually restarting the server (post crash).

P.S. to try and find out why Redis is crashing you can try looking at its log (usually found at /var/log).

Comment: I've had a look in /var/log/redis but unfortunately the logs are not displaying any useful recent information. I'll have another look next time we experience a crash.